# Regex match with accent in text and not in query

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex that match the keyword `pepe` in the string `Pépé Dominguez`

[image]

I don't want to sanitize the `Pépé dominguez` string before test.

Comment: That seems like a very specific regex. Are you sure you want to match `Pépé` and not all first names?

Comment: yes I want to match only `Pépé`

Comment: I want a regex with accent insensitive, for the case insensitive it's easy with i flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to match `Pepe` or `Pépé`, i would just do this:

```
/pépé|pepe/gi
```

Simple, but it works.

Comment: yes it works like this but I have to generate the `pépé` keyword. Because what I want to do is a `split` like this `"Pépé dominguez".split(regex)`